# react-native-admob working fine in iOS but not working in Android

Tags: admob, react-native, banner-ads

The App Id was created for Android in Google Admob and I have also created Ad Unit ID to display banner ads. The Test Ads are displayed perfectly well in Android Emulator, iOS Simulator and Live ads in Real iPhone devices. But unfortunately the ads are not working in Real Android Devices.

I am using this package
https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob

> Error: The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to
>   lack of ad inventory.

For the record my location is Gujarat, India and my device is Android P (Stock Android). 
I don't know what is going wrong. Region is the issue or the real android devices ?